# jquery val different from actual value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to setup CSRF protection in asp.net mvc but I'm having problems with the Ajax. It's mind boggling as to why.

I'm using the built in mvc token, which looks like this on the page:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="gnAeuskcQCq+bjF5bSKg/wyed65M2XNedTPmvKu/+tzCe1GEmIhyeUnurdMgg0ORjfkCBjyOYe78WS6TdJaPSeECTl7w5yjzgwb6TSLjR74cYE4Bd4lJ9YgBGCTyYXur+39inD60jtQh7VciTlM2ap9/YLim/RSCNMxbrs+KMZM=" />
```

The problem is that when I get the value using jquery it's different to whats on the page. So when I do this:

```
requestVerifStr = $(document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")).val();
```

I get this value:

```
X1WV+xrlkKXYjmLZS+OpPfjgeEPGjM/CjOSk0nKwV6iu3rCpHAo2XIDlJcX2ef4hBnK/BYrZw6xICQWqd8a7yJOjngDn1Yf7AKEl2uwLAtMXQQuRJkCzpq+lOWVv1Jyuud6dEIRiaXT0koGDxycps9wQoXvvnMlF1/4G5LDp9Y0=
```

I'm assuming there's some type of conversion jquery is doing.

Comment: Consider actually using jQuery: `$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()`

Comment: It's not a fix, it's a suggestion. As for your question... isn't that the actual value? It looks like the actual value. What do you see in the source?

Comment: Is there more than one on the page (multiple forms?):  alert($('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').length)

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/G88jG/

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/AUYPe/

Comment: Works totally fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/yvhmg/

Comment: I think it's what @InfinitiesLoop suggests.

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop Hi no there isn't. I just dont understand what could be happening on the page that would cause this? some javascript or something? Looked everywhere mind boggling.

Comment: Maybe it's some asp.net mvc specific javascript, for protection or something.

Comment: @James_Dude Got a live sample page?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that there are multiple inputs with `name="__RequestVerificationToken"` and .val() only returns the *first* result.

Here is an example of how that would happen: http://jsfiddle.net/4qA9V/